# Fax save and print

Tags: printer, splitters

[Background]

I'm currently building an application to show alarm information on a screen for our local fire department. Because of legal reasons, I am not allowed to use software to receive the fax (although there will be a Fritzbox which seems to be magically excluded from this limitation :) ) using a software solution. After being received the fax gets processed using OCR and parsed. A cloud solution is not an option. I know that my Fritzbox can receive a fax and send it as an email, but as far as I know, it cannot send it as an email while still forwarding it to the original fax device.

[Question]

Seems like I need a fax device which can both print the received fax and save it to some digital storage like a network drive or email (to a local mail server) at the same time. Saving to a USB drive is not enough for obvious reasons. I'm open for other solutions. If there is a different device (like a router) that allows this, let me know.

Comment: how about 1. receive fax 2. save a copy internally 3. process OCR etc 4. use saved copy and dial out to send the original fax to the other fax machine.

Comment: Should work but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do it this way legally.

Comment: Probably not an option, but can you post the legal limitations?

Comment: The original is in german but it means more or less "No server or software solution, only a analog or digital fax is acceptable"